# How to find the space owner in the Confluence REST API?

Tags: confluence, confluence-rest-api

Poking around the REST API, I don't see a way to get the space owner.  I can get the permissions list, but it is confusing, since there are many entries (duplicates!) that don't mention an operation at all.

I'm using this Python wrapper: https://pypi.python.org/pypi/PythonConfluenceAPI. I'm not sure if that's limiting my options, but the raw REST API docs don't provide any clues.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can you please clarify what do you mean by Space Owner? Technically, in Confluence you do have a space permissions and it doesn't have owner. However, people with Space Administrator permissions can consider as an owner in most of the [use cases](https://community.atlassian.com/t5/Confluence-questions/Space-owner/qaq-p/333865). I would recommend you to take look at space permissions [document](https://confluence.atlassian.com/doc/space-permissions-overview-139521.html) as well :-)

Comment: Hmm, I think I have been misled by some clever hand-crafted content in my wiki.  It looked like an official "this is the space owner" badge, but is not.  Thanks.